# If the Jacobian of two functions is zero, how are the two functions related?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $ x^{1} = f^{1}(u^{1},u^{2})$ and $x^{2} = f^{2}(u^{1},u^{2}) $. If the Jacobian of $f^{1}$ and $f^{2}$ is identically equal to zero (i.e. equal to 0 for all values of $u^1$ and $u^2$), why does this mean that there must be a functional relations between $x^{1}$ and $ x^{2}$ such that there exists a function $\phi$ such that $\phi(x^{1},x^{2}) = 0$ ?

Comment: Do you mean the Jacobian is zero for all $u$?

Comment: Yes- the Jacobian should be identically zero.

Comment: @SiChen if you define $\phi(x^{1},x^{2})=det(J_{x^{1}})*det(J_{x^{2}})$, it is equal to zero

Comment: You need some more conditions, for example, the function $\phi = 0$ will satisfy the above. Presumably you mean $\phi(x) = 0 $ **iff** $x = f(u)$ for some $u$?

Comment: @Wmmoreno Your definition of $\phi$ does not make sense to me. There are no such things as $\det J_{x_1}$ and $\det J_{x_2}$; there is a single Jacobian determinant of the map $u\mapsto x$. And at any rate, the Jacobian is not a function of $x^1,x^2$ but rather a function of $u^1,u^2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Jacobian of two functions is $J(f^1, f^2) = \partial_x f^1 \partial_y f^2 - \partial_y f^1 \partial_x f^2$. This can be re-written as the dot product of the gradient of $f^1$ with the vector orthogonal to the gradient of $f^2$.

$0 = J(f^1, f^2) = (\partial_x f^1 , \partial_y f^1) \cdot (\partial_y f^2, -\partial_x f^2).$

So these two vectors are orthogonal over the whole domain, so the gradients of $f^1$ and $f^2$ are always parallel. Now consider a contour of constant $f^1$. It is constant because the gradient of $f^1$ is always perpendicular to this contour. But then the gradient of $f^2$ is also perpendicular to this contour. Hence $f^2$ cannot change value along this contour. Along this contour $f^2$ always takes the same value. Doing this for every value / contour of $f^1$ describes a function $q$ from the image of $f^1$ to the image of $f^2$. 
That is, we can express $f^2(u^1, u^2) = q(f^1(u^1, u^2))$ for some function $q$.

I find the above the most useful result. But we could also express it as requested: $\phi(x^1, x^2) = x^2 - q(x^1) = 0$ for $x^1 = f^1(u^1, u^2), x^2 = f^2(u^1, u^2)$ for all $(u^1, u^2)$.

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: I understand the proof if the contours are connected. But what about if they are not?

Comment: Then things get interesting!  The functional relation becomes multivalued. If a given isovalue of $f^1$ has multiple disjoint contours, then $f^2$ is constant along each contour, but can take a different value along each contour.
The [Reeb graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reeb_graph) of $f^1$ (or $f^2$) partitions the domain into regions within which the relation is single-valued. These regions meet at saddle points of $f^1$ (or $f^2$).
I wrote a paper using this in oceanography: <https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ocemod.2019.01.008>

Answer (score 1):

The functions $f^1$ and $f^2$ define a map into $\mathbb R^2$. For sufficiently smooth maps (continuously differentiable is enough), the Jacobian is identically zero if and only if the image has area zero. The image can still be pretty rough, since the derivative is allowed to vanish. For example, a polygonal tree with infinitely many branches can be the image of a line segment (hence, of a planar domain) under a $C^1$ map.

When does there exist $\phi$ that vanishes on the image of $f$, and only there? A silly answer is: *always*, just let $\phi=0$ on the image of $f$, and $1$ elsewhere. If the continuity of $\phi$ is required, then the image of $f$ must be closed. And this is the *only* restriction: for every closed subset $A\subset \mathbb R$ there is a $C^\infty$ smooth function $\phi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $\phi =0$ on $A$ and only there.

So, I think you need to clarify what you really want from the "functional relation" concept.