# Does a singular Jacobian matrix imply functional dependence?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

I often find the following "fact" mentioned in engineering mathematics texts and videos:

> If $f_1,...,f_n$ are $C^1$ functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that the Jacobian matrix of the map $(f_1,...,f_n)$ vanishes everywhere, then the $f_i$'s must be functionally related.

They seem to use the following definition of *functionally related*: There is some $C^1$ function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla\phi$ is nonzero everywhere, and
$\phi(f_1,...,f_n)=0$ everywhere.

It is easy to see (using chain rule and some elementary linear algebra) why this definition of *functionally related* would lead to the Jacobian being singular everywhere. But what intrigues me is the converse claim. I am unable to come up with a rigorous proof or a counterexample.  All the multivariable calculus books I have seen so far are silent on this point.

Any helpful pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using graphical representation? I mean consider xyz axes, take planes $P_1,P_2,P_3$, if the jacobian determinant is zero, it implies that atleast 2 of the planes are parallel/ coincident, hence functional dependence, and if Jacobian det is non zero, there is a unique solution for the 3 planes.

Comment: Yes, that was my first line of thought. But I could not arrive at a rigorous proof along that line. Basically, I get a nontrivial vector in the nullspace of the Jacobian, at each point, and I need to be able to piece these vectors together to get an integral curve. I seem to require some sort of continuity of these nullspace vectors, which I cannot pin down.

Comment: Does this help? It's in $R^2$ space https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544721/if-the-jacobian-of-two-functions-is-zero-how-are-the-two-functions-related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_1$, $\ldots$, $f_{k+1}$ such that the jacobian of $(f_1, \ldots, f_k)$ has maximal rank $k$, but the jacobian of $(f_1, \ldots,f_{k+1})$ has constant rank $k$. Then $f_{k+1}$ is a function of $f_1$, $\ldots$, $f_k$.

Indeed, any locus $(f_1,\ldots, f_k)=$ const is a manifold of codimension $k$. Because of the condition on the jacobian of $(f_1, \ldots,f_{k+1})$ the function $f_{k+1}$ is constant on such a locus. It follows that $f_{k+1}= F(f_1, \ldots, f_k)$, for $F$ function of $k$ variables. This function will be smooth, since the map $(f_1, \ldots, f_k)$ is a submersion.

$\bf{Added:}$ Let's explain why if $f_1$, $\ldots$, $f_k$ have jacobian of maximal rank $k$, and $\operatorname{grad}f$ is linearly dependent on $\operatorname{grad}f_1$, $\ldots$, $\operatorname{grad}f_k$, then $f$ is locally constant on any submanifold of the form $f_i = c_i$, $i=1, k$. Indeed, consider a smooth path $t \mapsto \phi(t)$ on such a submanifold. Then at every $t$ we have
$$\langle \operatorname{grad}f_i\ _ {\phi(t)}, \phi'(t)\rangle = 0$$ and by the linear dependence of the gradients we get
$$\langle \operatorname{grad}f _ {\phi(t)}, \phi'(t)\rangle = 0$$
and so the function $f(\phi(t))$ is constant in $t$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please give me some reference (preferably a book) where this idea has been elaborated.

Comment: @Arnab Chakraborty: There is a book by Narasimhan, Analysis on Real and Complex Manifolds, where functional dependence appears.